# Is there any way to count the number of times a certain value occurs in TypeScript array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The solutions of questions similar to this were not working for me. 
I have a large array of the form :

```
 defects = [
   {
    "ref":"https:abc.com",
    "createdAt":"2017-12-04T08:14:40.972Z",
    "createdBy":"xyz",
    "id":"DE67687",
    "name":"OMS",
    "priority":"4",
    "state":"Known Error",
    "description":"Please refer attached screen for error detail.",
    "environment":"Production",
    "flowStateChangedDate":"2018-12-10T13:58:15.309Z",
    "objectID":"179929498832","resolution":"None"
    },
    {
    "ref":"https:abc.com",
    "createdAt":"2018-10-18T09:02:07.817Z",
    "createdBy":"wer",
    "id":"684933",
    "name":"Unable to change password after Password Reset",
    "priority":"3","state":"Closed",
    "description":"ddnkdfnldk",
    "environment":"Production",
    "flowStateChangedDate":"2018-11-26T09:09:51.282Z",
    "objectID":"260911316696","resolution":"Code Change"
    },
    {
    "ref":"https:aqwer.com",
    "createdAt":"2018-11-26T13:10:51.393Z",
    "createdBy":"emddf","id":"123456",
    "name":"PROD eCommerce",
    "priority":"2",
    "state":"Closed",
    "description":"smd,mns",
    "environment":"Production",
    "flowStateChangedDate":"2019-01-16T11:03:24.691Z",
    "objectID":"269182859560",
    "resolution":"Code Change"
   }
]
```

I want to count the number of times a certain value of priority, state and resolution occur. Is there any way to do that?
I want my output array for counting status(for example) to read something like this:

```
{{State: "closed", count:2},{State:"Known error", count:2}}
```

Comment: How do you arrive at `{{Status: 1, count:0},{Status:2, count:1}}`?

Comment: That was just an example, of the output I want in the end. I edited my question. Now it will make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgbkfn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
 result = [];

  constructor() {
    var stateData = this.groupBy(this.defects, "state");
    this.result =  Object.keys(stateData).map(item => ({state: item, count: stateData[item].length}))
    console.log(this.result)
  }

  groupBy(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  }
```

Modify your ngOninit like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._defectService.getDefects().subscribe(data => {
      this.defects = data;
      //defect = this.mapData(this.defects = data)
      console.log(this.defects);
      this.getStatusTotals();
    });

  }
```

Comment: tried this solution but for some reason, nothing is getting printed in console.log

Comment: Have you checked the demo?

Comment: Don't do it in constructor, do after `defects ` is completely loaded. Can you share your code in stackbiltz?

Comment: I am adding this code after defects is loaded, but it's not working

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htgtea?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202780/discussion-between-shasha0607-and-adrita-sharma).

Comment: `this.getStatusTotals();` should be called within subscribe, not outside, check modified answer

Answer (score 2):

```js
const defects = [{"ref":"https:abc.com",
"createdAt":"2017-12-04T08:14:40.972Z",
"createdBy":"xyz",
"id":"DE67687",
"name":"OMS",
"priority":"4",
"state":"Known Error",
"description":"Please refer attached screen for error detail.",
"environment":"Production",
"flowStateChangedDate":"2018-12-10T13:58:15.309Z",
"objectID":"179929498832","resolution":"None"},

{"ref":"https:abc.com",
"createdAt":"2018-10-18T09:02:07.817Z",
"createdBy":"wer",
"id":"684933",
"name":"Unable to change password after Password Reset",
"priority":"3","state":"Closed",
"description":"ddnkdfnldk",
"environment":"Production",
"flowStateChangedDate":"2018-11-26T09:09:51.282Z",
"objectID":"260911316696","resolution":"Code Change"},

{"ref":"https:aqwer.com",
"createdAt":"2018-11-26T13:10:51.393Z",
"createdBy":"emddf","id":"123456",
"name":"PROD eCommerce",
"priority":"2",
"state":"Closed",
"description":"smd,mns",
"environment":"Production",
"flowStateChangedDate":"2019-01-16T11:03:24.691Z",
"objectID":"269182859560",
"resolution":"Code Change"}];


let result = Object.entries(defects.reduce((acc, {state}) => {
 acc[state] = (acc[state] || 0) + 1
 return acc;
}, {})).map((o) => ({'state': o[0], count: o[1]}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried using this code, I'm not getting any thing printed on console

Comment: copy paste this on your browser console or click on Run Code snippet - seems it is working